# MATLAB - performing multiple integrations

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I'm trying to model deflection in a beam due to applied forces. Essentially this is taking a triple integral of a function. I attempted this using function handles.

```
u = @(x) x>=0; %unit step function
V = @(x) u(x-a)*F_a + u(x-b)*F_b + u(x-c)*F_c;
M = @(x) integral(V,0,x,'ArrayValued',true);
S = @(x) integral(M,0,x,'ArrayValued',true);
D = @(x) integral(D,0,x,'ArrayValued',true);
```

Calculating M is fine, but predictably, any latter functions take impossibly long to calculate. I'm assuming this is because each integral is recursively calling the integral before it amounting to too many calculations.

Without the ArrayValued parameter I get the error `"Error using integral (line 85) A and B must be floating-point scalars."`

Bonus question: The integrals are giving me this warning: 
`"Warning: Minimum step size reached near x = 320.5. There may be a singularity, or the tolerances may be too tight for this problem.` How would I go about fixing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this your actual problem, or have you simplified it to use step functions? The integral of a step function is simple to calculate so numerical integration shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I understand I can do that, but I was hoping for some versatility in matlab. I wanted some insight on how to solve this problem because I will likely run into problems in the future where I will need to numerically solve the integrals.

Comment: In general, doing numerics on functions that are not continuous is hard. The error you are seeing is (I'm almost 100% sure) because Matlab is struggling to cope with a very quickly changing integrand without losing too much accuracy. For this problem, try using `integral3` which does triple integration in one step.

Comment: Actually, `integral3` probably wont help you because you are doing 3 integrations with respect to one variable. Sorry...